# url problems on a production server

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

On my dev server i have the next url

```
http://someUrl.com/index.php/home//index
```

and work fine, see the double slashes before method call.

on my production server the same url throws 404 error. Somebody can help me with this problem? some configuration on server mising ?

I using codeigniter 2.x for my project and apache2

Comment: is mod_rewrite enabled on your live machine?

Comment: Check your rewriting rules, they might be slightly different between the systems.

Comment: No, i never use on dev server mod_rewrite to change url

Comment: @marianis You have to be performing some rewrite rule unless you happen to have a directory called `index.php` with a subdirectory of `home` and a file named `index`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to put `index function` that you have at the end of the url

`http://www.someurl.com/index.php/home/`

You may have to set your routes.

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html

You may need to have the controller class and file names like Home.php and class name Home

Answer (score 0):

Check that your live web server has [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#AllowOverride) enabled for the web root.

It is possible that you are using `.htaccess` files to configure mod_rewrite like in [this](https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750) example.

Sample fix:

```
<Directory /var/www/webroot>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Where `/var/www/webroot` is the directory that contains your project.

Comment: My server has AllowOverride but is set to None in both servers